# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp] in Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

Please help. I am working on a Spring Boot Application that uses Spring JPA, Hateoas and Spring Data Rest MVC. The application can be broken down into 2 major parts a RESTFul API and a Web App. The Restful API Works perfectly. The only problem now is getting my JSP pages to work. I get the following log message when trying http://localhost:9003/home.

```
2015-04-06 21:09:02.016 WARN 6702 --- [nio-9003-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServletRegistration'
```

Application.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableWebMvc

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
       InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
       viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
       viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
       return viewResolver;
   }

}
```

WebController.java

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class WebController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public ModelAndView index() {
        return new ModelAndView("index");
    }

}
```

DVDController.java

```
import com.stalinkay.rentadvd.domain.DVD;
import com.stalinkay.rentadvd.service.DVDService;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.hateoas.Resource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/dvd")
public class DVDController {

    private final DVDService dvdService;

    @Autowired
    public DVDController(DVDService dvdService) {
        this.dvdService = dvdService;
    }

    /**
     * Create DVD
     *
     * @param requestDVD Spring uses the RequestBody to create a new DVD
     * to save to the database
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    HttpHeaders create(@RequestBody DVD requestDVD) {
        return dvdService.create(requestDVD);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve DVD
     *
     * @param dvdid
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{dvdid}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    Resource<DVD> retrieve(@PathVariable Long dvdid) {
        return dvdService.retrieve(dvdid);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve All DVDs
     *
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    List<Resource<DVD>> retrieveAll() {
        return dvdService.retrieveAll();
    }

    /**
     * Update DVD
     *
     * @param requestDVD Spring uses the RequestBody to create a new DVD
     * to save to the database
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    HttpHeaders update(@RequestBody DVD requestDVD) {
        return dvdService.update(requestDVD);
    }

    /**
     * Delete DVD
     *
     * @param dvdid
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{dvdid}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    void delete(@PathVariable Long dvdid) {
        dvdService.delete(dvdid);
    }
}
```

I included my DVDController.java just to show that I'm using @RestController for the RESTful API and @Controller for the Web App.

What can I do to get Spring to serve my JSP Pages? I don't want to use xml. And I would like to have both the RESTful API and the Web App in 1 project.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you have a WebApplicationInitializer implemented

Comment: No. Doesn't Spring Boot take care of that?

Comment: @faljbour, isn't the ViewResolver supposed to be sufficient for that?

Comment: no, I do not think so, you need to create a dispatcher servlet and register it.

Comment: unless you have it defined in a web.xml file

Comment: Are you aware of the limitations when using JSPs with the embedded tomcat? http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations

Comment: @ci_ I wasn't aware of the limitations but after looking through that I'm within safe limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up with.

Application.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Updated application.properties to:

```
spring.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.view.suffix: .jsp
```

I had @EnableWebMvc and that was also causing the view resolution issues.

I stumbled upon this by looking at [Spring's spring-boot-sample-web-jsp](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp).

Comment: The link that you're referring to is broken. The solution that you've proposed doesn't work in my case! :(